# Python selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I faced issue when I execute a python script to send sms from my 4G router. The code run perfectly fine on my development machine. But when I run it on a Raspberry Pi 4B running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, it says gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 23, in main
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: headless chrome=98.0.4758.80)
```

I've install `chromedriver` using `pip` and `apt` and other dependencies using `snap`
Here's the output when I execute `chromedriver`:

```
$ chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 98.0.4758.80 (7f0488e8ba0d8e019187c6325a16c29d9b7f4989-refs/branch-heads/4758@{#972}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

Here's my python code:

```
import time
# import sys
import argparse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-n", '--number', help="Phone number")
    parser.add_argument("-m", '--message', help="Message to be sent")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Add options
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")

    # # Variables initialization
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    # message = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in sys.argv[2:]])
    message = args.message
    numbers = args.number.split(' ')

    # # Print arguments
    print('Phone number: ', numbers)
    print('Message: '+message)


    driver.get("https://192.168.0.1")
    print('Logging in...')
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'main'))
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "submit").click()
    driver.get("https://192.168.0.1/uir/sys_smsmsg.htm")
    for index, number in enumerate(numbers):
        print('Typing message...')
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "S801E2701").clear()
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "S801E2701").send_keys(number)
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "S801E2801").clear()
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "S801E2801").send_keys(message)
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "submit").click()
        print('Sending message ', index+1, '/', str(len(numbers)), '...')
        # driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
        time.sleep(4)
    print('Message sent, exiting...')
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The implication from web searches is that this generally means a mismatch between the version of Selenium and the version of Chrome.

Comment: Why can't you send the message directly, instead of going through another local web site?

Comment: @TimRoberts 1. What do you mean by "implication from web searches"? 
2. Does your second question asking about my use case?

Comment: @TimRoberts So which one should I upgrade or downgrade? And to which version? Thank you.

Comment: (1) What I mean is that I Googled your errors, as you could have done..  90% of the questions I answer here are answers from Google.  (2) Yes.  You are bringing up a fake web browser to make a web request of a local computer to send your SMS.  Whatever that local web server is doing, you code do in this code directly without involving web requests.

Comment: Don't know.  If you have upgraded Selenium, then perhaps you'll need to get an older Chrome driver.